# Stripe, Canceling Subscription Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

Im trying to cancel a subscription which is already created. I did pass the correct customer id and plan id. Yet i get an error in my terminal saying

```
Stripe::InvalidRequestError (Customer cus_xxxxxxxxxxx does not have a subscription with ID Golden)
```

Here are my controller methods.

```
def create
    sub_plan = params[:plan_id]
    subscription_plan_id = SubscriptionPlan.where(plan_id:sub_plan).first.id
    token = params[:stripeToken]
    email = current_user.email
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :card => token,
    :plan => sub_plan,
    :email => email
    )
    Subscription.create(subscription_plan_id:subscription_plan_id,user_id:current_user.id,stripe_customer_token:customer[:id])
    redirect_to '/membership'
  end

  def destroy
    p "---------------------------"
    subscription_plan_id = SubscriptionPlan.where(plan_id:params[:plan_id]).first.id
    customer_id = Subscription.where(subscription_plan_id:subscription_plan_id,user_id:current_user.id).first.stripe_customer_token
    customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(customer_id) 
    customer.subscriptions.retrieve(params[:plan_id]).delete()
    Subscription.where(subscription_plan_id:subscription_plan_id,user_id:current_user.id).first.destroy
  end
```

in my create method a user creates a subscription which happens successfuly, It appears on my stripe account too..
But on trying to destroy it this error occurs. Is there anything wrong. Pls help. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stripe subscription can't be retrieve with a plan id.

To retrieve a subscription : first you need a customer :

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve("cus_xxxxxxxxxx")
```

With the customer you can retrieve all his subscriptions :

```
subscriptions = customer.subscriptions.data
```

Or a specific subscription with retrieve method and stripe_id of subscription ( doc ref : https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#retrieve_subscription ) :

```
subscription = customer.subscriptions.retrieve("sub_xxxxxxxxxx")
```

Hope this helps